# while i am compiling i am getting error as not implemented

Tags: python-3.x, scikit-learn

while i am compiling below code i am getting error i dont know why i am getting this error

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
from sklearn.metrics.pairwise import cosine_similarity

vectorizer=TfidfVectorizer( ngram_range=(1,1))

similarity = []
for i in range(0,len(data)):
j = a['question1'].iloc[i]
k  = a['question2'].iloc[i]
inputs = []
inputs.append(j)
inputs.append(k)
try:
    inputs = (vectorizer.fit_transform(inputs))
except ValueError:
    inputs=[]
    inputs.append(0)
    inputs.append(0)
j = inputs[0]
k =inputs[1]
j = np.reshape(j,(1,-1))
k = np.reshape(k,(1,-1))
similarity.append(cosine_similarity(j, k))
```

i am getting error as

```
 NotImplementedError: Reshaping not implemented for csr_matrix.
```

Answer (score 0):

`TfidfVectorizer.transform()` returns a sparse matrix. So reshaping is not possible on that. Convert that to dense array first. Try:

```
try:
    inputs = vectorizer.fit_transform(inputs).toarray()
except ValueError:
    inputs=[]
    inputs.append(0)
    inputs.append(0)
```